# Split string into character and numbers and store in a map Python

Tags: python, regex, string, split, numbers

I've a string like

> 'A15B7C2'

It represents count of the character.

I am using ***re*** right now to split it into characters and numbers. After that will eventually store it in a dict

```
import re
data_str = 'A15B7C2'
re.split("(\d+)", data_str)
# prints --> ['A', '15', 'B', '7', 'C', '2', '']
```

But if I have a string like

> 'A15B7CD2Ef5'

it means that count of C is 1 (its implicit) and count of Ef is 5. (Uppercase and subsequent lowercase count as one key) consequently I get

> 'CD' = 2 (Not correct)
>   'Ef' = 5 (Correct)

How do modify it to provide me proper count?
Whats the best approach to parse and get count and store in a dict?

Comment: So, you can't split with one or more digits any longer. What have you tried to solve the problem? Are  your strings alphanumeric?

Comment: @Wiktor : Did tried.. `r"[^\W\d_]+|\d+"` `r"(\d+|\s+)"` `"([A-Za-z])([0-9]*)"` and some others but just wasn't able to get the regex right. 
Looking at the answer, turned out a little more focus would have helped ;) Also even then I would not have been able to write the whole thing down in one! line :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this all in one fell swoop:

```
In [2]: s = 'A15B7CD2Ef5'

In [3]: {k: int(v) if v else 1 for k,v in re.findall(r"([A-Z][a-z]?)(\d+)?", s)}
Out[3]: {'A': 15, 'B': 7, 'C': 1, 'D': 2, 'Ef': 5}
```

The regex is essentially a direct translation of your requirements, leveraging `.findall` and capture groups:

```
r"([A-Z][a-z]?)(\d+)?"
```

Essentially, an uppercase letter that may be followed by a lowercase letter as the first group, and a digit that may or may not be there as the second group (this will return `''` if it isn't there.

A trickier example:

```
In [7]: s = 'A15B7CD2EfFGHK5'

In [8]: {k: int(v) if v else 1 for k,v in re.findall(r"([A-Z][a-z]?)(\d+)?", s)}
Out[8]: {'A': 15, 'B': 7, 'C': 1, 'D': 2, 'Ef': 1, 'F': 1, 'G': 1, 'H': 1, 'K': 5}
```

Finally, breaking it down with an even trickier example:

```
In [10]: s = 'A15B7CD2EfFGgHHhK5'

In [11]: re.findall(r"([A-Z](?:[a-z])?)(\d+)?", s)
Out[11]:
[('A', '15'),
 ('B', '7'),
 ('C', ''),
 ('D', '2'),
 ('Ef', ''),
 ('F', ''),
 ('Gg', ''),
 ('H', ''),
 ('Hh', ''),
 ('K', '5')]

In [12]: {k: int(v) if v else 1 for k,v in re.findall(r"([A-Z][a-z]?)(\d+)?", s)}
Out[12]:
{'A': 15,
 'B': 7,
 'C': 1,
 'D': 2,
 'Ef': 1,
 'F': 1,
 'Gg': 1,
 'H': 1,
 'Hh': 1,
 'K': 5}
```

Comment: The one line complete solution is great! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use some regex logic and [**`.span()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
([A-Z])[a-z]*(\d+)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/e9bxIV/1).

---

In `Python` this would be:

```
import re

string = "A15B7CD2Ef5"
rx = re.compile(r'([A-Z])[a-z]*(\d+)')

def analyze(string=None):
    result = []; lastpos = 0;
    for m in rx.finditer(string):
        span = m.span()
        if lastpos != span[0]:
            result.append((string[lastpos], 1))
        else:
            result.append((m.group(1), m.group(2)))
        lastpos = span[1]
    return result

print(analyze(string))
# [('A', '15'), ('B', '7'), ('C', 1), ('E', '5')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Search for the letters in the string, instead of digits.

```
import re
data_str = 'A15B7C2'
temp = re.split("([A-Za-z])", data_str)[1:]    # First element is just "", don want that
temp= [a if a != "" else "1" for a in temp]    # add the 1's that were implicit in the original string
finalDict = dict(zip(temp[0::2], temp[1::2]))  # turn the list into a dict
```

Answer (score 0):

In keeping with your original logic.  Instead of using re.split() we can find all the numbers, split the string on the first match, keep the second half of the string for the next split, and store your pairs as tuples for later.

```
import re

raw = "A15B7CD2Ef5"
# find all the numbers
found = re.findall("(\d+)", raw)
# save the pairs as a list of tuples
pairs = []
# check that numbers where found
if found:
    # iterate over all matches
    for f in found:
        # split the raw, with a max split of one, so that duplicate numbers don't cause more then 2 parts
        part = raw.split(f, 1)
        # set the original string to the second half of the split
        raw = part[1]
        # append pair
        pairs.append((part[0], f))



# Now for fun expand values
long_str = ""
for p in pairs:
    long_str += p[0] * int(p[1])

print pairs
print long_str
```